# Why isn't my background showing?

Tags: css

My background image isn't showing up no matter what I try. I want it to span the whole background space.

Here is my CSS:

```
body {
    background-image: url('../Project2/images/water.jpg') no-repeat center top;
    background-size: cover;
    font-family:    Lucida Grande, Lucida Sans, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:      100%;
    *font-size:     80%;
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block; 
}
```

Comment: did you try only with background property, or ensuring the path to the file is correct? You can check in 'developer tools' in Chrome if the path is the one you expect

Comment: please ensure that your path to the image is the correct one...

Answer (score 2):

You are using the `background-image` property which takes only one value, the url of the image, but you have inserted multiple values.

To do what you want, change `background-image` to just `background`, which is the shorthand version of `background-image` and allows you to include mutltiple property values.

[background-image](https://drafts.csswg.org/css2/colors.html#propdef-background-image)

[background](https://drafts.csswg.org/css2/colors.html#propdef-background)

Answer (score 1):

Adapting the code from this [CSS Trick](https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/), ensure you use

`background` (instead of `background-image`) and combine with the `cover` property for size.

I added the code for a div for this example only  (you can remove it to apply to body, as well as remove the height property)

Assuming this is your folder structure

```
Project
  |_ index.html
  |_ images/
  |        |_water.jpg
  |_ css/
        |_style.css
```

Then the url should be: `url("../images/water.jpg")`

```css
div {
  background: url("http://placehold.it/400x400") no-repeat center top fixed;  
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  
  font-family: Lucida Grande, Lucida Sans, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 100%;
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div>hello world</div>
```

Comment: I tried adding that, and it's still not working. I have everything saved to the same folder, but in that folder I have an images folder.....could that be the problem?

Comment: @AliObermayer yes, that could be the problem.  Try changing the path of the image to `./images/water.jpg`?

Comment: ok i tried that, there was still no change. I seriously have no idea what the problem is. Someone else just said to put my images folder inside my css folder, i think im going to try that and see what happens

Comment: @AliObermayer not a good idea - please tell me where you have the html file, where is the images folder and where is the CSS file (and maybe the path is `../images/water.jpg` ?)

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: I'm glad I could help! If the answer was helpful, mark it as a accepted

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
body {
    background-image: url("paper.gif");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: I tried that and its still not working :(

Comment: try only the image url and work your way up from there. if you can put the image file in the same folder as your css file to make sure you can read the file. Maybe something is wrong with the path or folder name. the url you have. ../ stand for the root folder of you site.  Make sure you take the capital P into account.